# Why is a negative size_t underflowing but subtracting it does not?

Tags: c++, integer, size-t, underflow

I have this simple program here which is returning 18446744073709551615:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<-(size_t)1;
    cout<<0-(size_t)1;
    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, I also have this program here which is returning the expected result 0:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<1-(size_t)1;
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening here? If `-(size_t)1` and `0-(size_t)1` are underflowing, why is `1-(size_t)1` fine?

Comment: `1-1` is `0`. Why are you expecting underflow? You're not doing `1 + -(size_t)1`, you're subtracting, and subtraction is not the same thing as adding the negation programmatically.

Comment: @ShadowRanger So shouldnt -(size_t)1 evaluate to large number and then it will become 1+large number?

Comment: @churill Right, but in the latter order of operations, I would expect -(size_t)1 to first turn into a large number

Comment: No, because you didn't do addition of a negative, you subtracted. Negation and subtraction are independent. Unary negation is not related to binary subtraction.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Then why are these results doing the same thing as i posted:     cout<<-1*(size_t)1;
    cout<<2 + -1*(size_t)1;

Comment: Except that you are not evaluating `-(size_t)1`. You are subtracting `(size_t)1` from something else. `-` means both a negation or subtraction, depending on the context. You're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @StarckOverflar I think what you are thinking of if `1 + (-(size_t)1` which is mathematically equivalent. `-(size_t)1` wraps around to the largest possible `size_t` value. What happens in the case you are thinking of is you get `1 + max_size_t_value` which wraps around back to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

> why is 1-(size_t)1 fine?

Because it doesn't overflow. 1 is representable as `std::size_t`, and the result of subtraction is 0 which is also representable.

> So shouldnt -(size_t)1 evaluate to large number

It would, as you've found out when you used the unary minus operator in the first eample. But you didn't use the unary minus operator in the second example. You used the binary minus operator.

> then it will become 1+large number?

A subtraction doesn't "become" an addition.

That said, you'll find that  `1 + std::size_t(-1)` is also 0. This is because unsigned arithmetic is modular. -1 is congruent with some large value, and that large value + 1 is congruent with 0. This property of modular arithmetic is known as *"compatibility with translation"*.